# Finding the sum of the areas of all the squares that are in geometric progression.

Tags: sequences-and-series

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO4Go.jpg)

I already found out that the series is a G.P.

For the part about the sum of all squares, I thought of solving it using "sum to infinity of G.P. formula" but the absolute value of the ratio(r) of the progression(|r|) must be less than 1 while it is 2.

I thought of using sum of G.P. series: $S_n = \frac {a(1-r^n)}{(1-r)}$ but I don't know how many terms there are.

Comment: Presumably there are infinitely many...there's no indication that the process is meant to stop somewhere.  Note:  I don't understand what "...must be less than $1$ while it is $2$" means.

Comment: @lulu The absolute value of the ratio must be less than 1 in order to put it in sum to infinity formula but the ratio in this G.P series is 2.

Comment: $r=\frac{1}{2}$ not $2$.

Comment: $S_ \infty = \frac {a}{(1-r)}$

Comment: @LionHeart Oh yes, I messed up. Thanks. It's all settled now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted comment by @LionHeart:

> $r=\frac12$ not $2.$

(This is a [community wiki answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki), in order for the post to leave the "unanswered questions" queue.)